# Error In Javascript code with php

Tags: javascript, php

I wanna make statistics in my website for the last 3 years

I want to show result like this

```
2016 : 159
2015 : 132
2014 : 200
```

I try my code (this's)

```
$date2 = date('Y');
$n = $date2;
for($i=$n-2;$i<=$n;$i++) {
$sql = "SELECT sum(count) AS value_sum FROM statistics where YEAR(st_date) = $i ";
$sql_sel = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo '
    <script>
    var pieData = [
   ';

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_sel)) {
if($i == $n-2) {
echo '{
    value: '.$rows['value_sum'].',
    color:"#337AB7"
  },';
}
else if($i == $n-1) {
echo '{
    value: '.$rows['value_sum'].',
    color:"#FC8213"
    },';
  }
else if($i == $n) {
  echo '{
    value: '.$rows['value_sum'].',
    color:"#8BC34A"
  },';
}
echo'];
new Chart(document.getElementById("pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
</script>';
}}
?>
```

but this code give me just 1 one row like this

2016 : 159

I wanna see all result, any help ?

Comment: PROTIP: You can build an array in PHP then use `json_encode()` to create a JSON string, which can actually be echoed into the JavaScript and parsed as an array/object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm beginner Can you help me ? and I need to change color for Each year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out:

```
<?php
// Store the array for the pie data within PHP at first
$js_pie_data = [];

// Define colors
$colors = [
    date('Y') => '8BC34A',  // current year
    (date('Y') - 1) => 'FC8213', // last year
    (date('Y') - 2) => '337AB7' // 2 years ago
];

$sql = "SELECT
            YEAR(st_date) as `year`, -- get year from DB, makes life simpler :)
            sum(count) AS value_sum
        FROM
            statistics
        WHERE
            YEAR(st_date) >= (YEAR(CURDATE())-2) -- get all records from 2 years ago to today
        GROUP BY
            YEAR(st_date) -- group by year so that our sum() above will work";

$sql_sel = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_sel))
{
    // keep adding entries to the pie data
    $js_pie_data[] = [
        'value' => $rows['value_sum'],
        'color' => '#'.$colors[$rows['year']] // based on year from DB, pick a color
    ];
}

echo '<script>
var pieData = '.json_encode($js_pie_data).'; // this will output a properly formatted JS array which will be understood by JS with no problem
new Chart(document.getElementById("pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
</script>';
```

Comment: That's perfect, can I make the same for month ? without any problem ?

Comment: @sayousaad I'm not sure what you mean but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: Why should this "help out" the OP? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard Would you like me to comment more thoroughly?

Comment: Not so much comment but explain why you do what you do.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating 3 charts within your for loop. If you allow php to encode the data for you, you can echo the script outside of the PHP like so:

```
$date2 = date('Y');
$n = $date2;
$data = array();
for($i=$n-2;$i<=$n;$i++) {
    $sql = "SELECT sum(count) AS value_sum FROM statistics where YEAR(st_date) = $i ";
    $sql_sel = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_sel)) {
        if($i == $n-2) {
            $data[] = array('value'=> $rows['value_sum'], 'color'=>'#337AB7');
        }
        else if($i == $n-1) {
            $data[] = array('value'=> $rows['value_sum'], 'color'=>'#FC8213');
        }
        else if($i == $n) {
            $data[] = array('value'=> $rows['value_sum'], 'color'=>'#8BC34A');
        }
    }
}
?>

<script>
    var pieData = <?php json_encode($data) ?>;
    new Chart(document.getElementById("pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
</script>
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: If you look at the source code, does the script look correct?

Answer (score 0):

1)You can create array in php side.

2)Then convert it as json string.

3)Define javascript variable with that json string

4)Convert it as object with JSON.parse

5)Insert it in option

```
 <?php

    $db = Array("1","2","3");

    $out = Array();

    $x = 0;
        foreach($db as $vals){

            if($x == 1){
            $out[] = Array("value"=>$vals,"color"=>"#bfbfbf");
            }

            if($x == 2){
            $out[] = Array("value"=>$vals,"color"=>"#00ffff");
            }

            if($x == 3){
            $out[] = Array("value"=>$vals,"color"=>"#fff00");
            }


        if($x == 3){$x = 0;}
        $x++;
        }



    echo "
    <script language='javascript'> 

    var stat_str = '".json_encode($out)."';
    var stat_obj = JSON.parse(stat_str);

    // then you can insert stat_obj if you need object into stats
    </script>";
    ?>
```